# WebPack + static JS files + Base64

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron, bundle

I am developing a project in ElectronJS. While new to WebPack. WebPack packs everything into one file. But there are several files - js scripts, which are simply stored in JS files (JS libraries for the browser) And now they are included with the code:

```
let fileContent = fs.readFileSync(`./script.js`, 'utf8')
```

How can I make WebPack encode this file into a Base64 string and put this string into a common bundle?

It would also be nice to pack the index.html file into a bundle

Comment: Can you give more background: why are you using `readFileSync()` instead of the more usual `require` or `import` commands?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My electron project is a robot: browser automation. And I execute these JS libraries in the browser itself, and not in the project code.
Therefore, they must be read as a simple string that can be executed in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think (untested) you can treat those additional files as a resource, so in your webpack.config.js you'd have:

```
   module: {
     rules: [
       ...
       {
         test: /^(script1|script2)\.js$/i,
         type: 'asset/resource',
       },
       ...
     ]
   }
```

Obviously change the regex and/or add more rules, to cover all your files.
Reference: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/

This assumes you have a good reason for not using `require` or `import`, and letting Webpack automatically discover them as a dependency, of course.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Darren. But how can I refer to these scripts in the Electron code itself?
Right now I'm writing: let fileContent = fs.readFileSync(`./script.js`, 'utf8')
And how to refer to assets?

Comment: I think webpack will keep them in the same place relative to your index.html? I.e. it'll work in exactly the same way as a png image file would. In lieu of reading the docs, I've sometimes used trial and error to track down the correct relative path to use :-)

Comment: In the end - what I came up with.
1. I obfuscated my js libraries and turned them into strings
2. Created a libs.js file in which I wrote
   const lib1 = `obfuscated script here`
   const lib2 = `obfuscated script here`
3. Connected libs.js with the usual require